# Hashable Pandas DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, hash, memoization, datetimeindex

I'm trying to memoize a method `foo(dti: DatetimeIndex)` using the `@functools.lru_cache()` annotation.  However, it complains with `TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'`.

Since `DatetimeIndex` objects are immutable, there should be a good way to use them as a key for memoization, right?

Also, what would be wrong with `DatetimeIndex` defining a hash method to simply return its `id()`?

Comment: Not "memorize", memoize.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization .

Comment: I want to cache it simply because it's expensive to calculate `foo`.  In my case it's an intrinsically expensive operation, there's little I can do to make it faster.

Comment: Yes, it is, otherwise I wouldn't be looking for a solution.  I'm not sure why you doubt it.  For an example: suppose the user gets to interactively input arbitrary integers and we want to prime factorize each one.  There's no way to avoid re-work unless you cache the output of previous factorizations.  This is a situation like that - I don't know what `DatetimeIndex` values I'm going to see, but I want to avoid redoing work I've already done recently.

Comment: No, it needs to see the entire `DatetimeIndex` object.  It's a function of the entire object.

Comment: I'm sorry @MaxU, but this is already the exact question I want to ask, and I really don't get why you think it's ill-defined or shouldn't be asked.  The question is about memoizing and hashing of `DatetimeIndex` objects, not whether I can optimize some other calling code that's not up for discussion.

Comment: ok, sorry for that - i have deleted all my "off-topic" questions! good luck!

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Curious that this question has not received more attention.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up writing my own decorator to be able to memoize methods that accept `DataFrame` objects (or `Hashable` objects, in case `DataFrame`s get hashable in the future), it looks like this:

```
def my_memoize(func):
    # TODO use an LRU cache so we don't grow forever
    cache = {}

    def decorating_function(self, arg):
        key = arg if isinstance(arg, collections.Hashable) else id(arg)
        key = (self, key)
        if key in cache:
            return cache[key]
        value = func(self, arg)
        cache[key] = value
        return value

    return decorating_function
```

I use it like so:

```
@my_memoize
def calculate_stuff(self, df):
    ...
```

Comment: This will return an incorrect result if a DatetimeIndex is deallocated and a new, non-equivalent one is subsequently allocated at same memory address. The problem with using id() as part of a cache key is that it carries no guarantee of uniqueness for objects with non-overlapping lifetimes.

Comment: How did this _incorrect_ (according to @TJM) solution worked out ?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris it worked out fine for me, because I wasn't doing any deallocation in this case and the objects always stayed at their original addresses.

Comment: Another alternative would be to specifically recognize `DatetimeIndex` objects and compute a hash by iterating over all its entries, or by sticking an integer "ear tag" (in the sense of wildlife management) on each `DatetimeIndex` as it's presented to us and using that to build the hash.  Should work fine since these objects are immutable, so we don't really need to care about the actual date values.

Comment: @KenWilliams Would you mind explaining what deallocation means? I also have one and only `DatetimeIndex` which should stay as generated in first place throughout the entire execution of my program which includes multiple operations that need the same timestamps. As for the alternative, you mean to check for a `DatetimeIndex` instance, if positive then build a hash either iterating over each and every timestamp or else build a hash on an "enumaration" of the timestamps ?